# Seed Job environment variable ${WORKSPACE} is assigned to child jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-groovy

Create a Seed Job using DSL that would create 5 Child Jobs. As part of build step I've to use ${WORKSPACE} environment variable, which should read the value from the slave machine where the child Job is running. But however when the child jobs are created, the workspace value is replaced with SeedJobs  workspace location from master server.

How would I restrict  seed job not to inject its ${WORKSPACE} value.

Could some one help me on this please.

Thanks
Mano

Comment: Can you show the build step where you are referencing the ${WORKSPACE} env var?

Comment: As a workaround I have set the ${WORKSPACE} as an environment with hard coded value  to each child job. 
But now I've another case, for every build a binary is generated say for example build.${BUILD_ID}.rpm. This is a build step that should go as part of every child job and the BUILD_ID should be the child  build job id. But however the build_id from seed job is injected into child jobs.

Comment: Say if child jobs build id is 3  and the seed job build id is 45 , so  I would be expecting  the output should be build.3.rpm . But I'm getting a binary with build.45.rpm . Even if I build the child job manually, the build id of seed job is being appended with build name

Comment: You should probably update your question to reflect the question in the last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to the BUILD_NUMBER of the *generated job* in your job-dsl code, you should code it as follows :

```
"\${BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

The important part is the \ before the **$** sign which prevents the evaluation of the BUILD_NUMBER variable as it pertains to the Goovy runtime that is (likely) your Jenkins job-dsl seed job.

The config.xml of the generated job will contain **${BUILD_NUMBER}** instead of a digit that represents you build number of your seed-job. And then your generated job will evaluate that when it runs.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that works !!!! Build number is evaluated as part of generated job. \ before the $sign was preventing the seed job to evaluate during its execution.
Thanks Again!!

Comment: I'm delighted! I've been up to my eyeballs in job-dsl for the last year so keep the questions coming.